# Xamarin iOS UIView Has No DrawLayer override

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm currently translating an `iOS` app in `XCode` / `Swift` to `Xamarin` `iOS`.

In the existing swift code, there is a custom control that inherits from `UIView`, and overrides the `drawLayer` func.

However, when I try to override the same member in my `UIView` custom control in `Xamarin`, there is no override.

Can someone help me work out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method does not exist directly to use this you have to use CALayer class itself.

e.g.

```
public class BlueView : UIView
{
    [Export ("layerClass")]
    public static Class GetLayerClass ()
    {
        return new Class (typeof (BlueLayer));
    }

    public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
    {
        // Do nothing, the Layer will do all the drawing
    }
}

public class BlueLayer : CALayer
{
    public override void DrawInContext (CGContext ctx)
    {
        ctx.SetFillColor (0, 0, 1, 1);
        ctx.FillRect (Bounds);
    }
}
```

Ref:

[CALayer Details](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.CoreAnimation.CALayer/)

[CALayer With UIView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIView/)